# How to implement Action Bar Activity and App Compat Activity together

Tags: android-actionbaractivity, android-appcompat

I want to integrate my Navigation Drawer Android Studio project,
 which is implemented by extending MainActivity by ActionBarActivity
 into other project that extends MainActivity by AppCompat Activity 
and now my application is crashing because of it.

I debugged the code of Navigation Drawer project and other project

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Above metioned methods causes Navigation Drawer app to enter ActionBarActivity.class
and the other project into AppCompat.class and then my application crashes.
I tried finding solution on internet but I keep getting solutions for Action Bar.
If you need sample code to figure out any details please let me know

Comment: Are you using the `v7` or `v4` library for `ActionBarDrawerToggle`? Check your `import delcarations` if you are unsure.

Comment: @PPartisan i checked it's v7